Why this huge difference in WPF System.Timers.Timer function in DEBUG mode and RELEASE mode ( using Timer(2) as example )
Timer(2) in RELEASE mode should execute 500 calls per second ( 1000/N ) but it only executes 65 calls per second, probably because the 15 ms system timer resolution. In DEBUG mode it executes these 500 calls per second which indicate a much more precise system timer. I can not find any explanation for that.

There is a similar question related to ASP.NET (I am not sure whether the solutions apply to your specific problem): Systems.Timers.Timer works in debug, but not release.

Thank Olivier but unfortunately, it does not apply to my specific problem. It does not explain how a Timer (in Debug mode) can be so precise to work at 2 ms.
